# Angular submit form data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using ng-flow library to load images to server and after user dragged and dropped image, I can get HTML 5 file image to my controller and I need to download it to server together with the ohter parameters, like currency, subject etc. I googled and find that the best way is to convert to json form data and send with POST method. When I got the response from server, I see that form data contains subject but does not contains the image. What could be wrong?

In following code url is real, you can try to get your own response.

Angular code:

```
 var file = $flow.files[0];
 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://yuppi.com.ua/server/rest/add.php?key=453sdfg3t&action=add",            
            headers: { 'Content-Type': false },

            transformRequest: function (data) {

                 var formData = new FormData();

                 formData.append("subject",  angular.toJson(data.subject));
                 formData.append("file", data.file);

                 return formData;                
            },

            data: { subject: subject, file: file}
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

PHP code:

```
$form = file_get_contents("php://input");

echo "Form: ";  print_r($form);
```

var_dump of $_FILES

```
"array(1) {
  ["photo"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "gradient-2.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpY8nqji"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(442567)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is in your $_POST variable in PHP?

Comment: @progsource you mean `$_FILES` right? because `$_POST` doesn't populate with uploaded files.

Comment: $_POST and $_FILES variables are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send your form data to your controller,try this :

> data: { subject: subject, data: formData}

and also you need to define formData at first to send through the $http .Try this at the end :

```
var file = $flow.files[0]; 
var formData = new FormData();

 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://yuppi.com.ua/server/rest/add.php?key=453sdfg3t&action=add",            
            headers: { 'Content-Type': false },

            transformRequest: function (data) {

                 formData.append("subject",  angular.toJson(data.subject));
                 formData.append("file", data.file);

                 return formData;                
            },

            data: { subject: subject, data: formData}
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(data);
        });
```

and for php part you can use this function that i have written :

```
function uplFile($fn,$path='upload/'){ 
    $delim = explode(';base64,',$fn);
    $type = str_replace('data:','',$delim[0]);
    switch ($type) { 
        case "image/gif": 
            $type = '.gif';
            break; 
        case "image/jpeg": 
            $type = '.jpg';
            break; 
        case "image/png": 
            $type = '.png';
            break; 
        case "image/bmp": 
            $type = '.bmp';
            break; 
    } 
    $data = base64_decode($delim[1]);  
    $file = uniqid() .$type;
    $success = file_put_contents($path.$file, $data);
    return $file;
}
```

This function gets formData() contents as first parameter and gets upload location for second parameter.For your data you can use it easily as below:

```
uplFile($_POST['file']);
```

Comment: This is my response from get_file_contenets, but POST and files are still empty.---------------------------27672246989232
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

50
-----------------------------27672246989232
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="eye.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG

Comment: so it sends the data, can you tell me whats the result of `print_r($_POST)` ?

Comment: Now $_POST is ok, I see all parameters, and $_FILES also is not empty, but seems that val['tmp_file'] doesn't contains my file

Comment: @user1315599 yes , you're right. That's why you're using system FormData() object.The result contains two part.first the image type and the second one is the image `base64` encoded that has been delimitered by semicolon.i have updated my answer.check it !

Comment: I did var_dump of $_POST variable and there is no 'photo' parameter. Maybe it is in file?

Comment: I'hve added var_dump of $_FILES variable in my question. There is size() atribute.

Comment: look at this `data: { subject: subject, data: formData}`  . you will only have subject and data parameter. where is the problem ?